# My laptop fan is making a rattling sound

Tags: laptop, fan

so 2 weeks ago I heard this very very loud rattling fan noise
and the next day I opened my laptop and used some compressed
air 1 week later the sound returned but it fixed itself somehow
now today I woke up and guess what the sound is back and this
time it doesnt fix itself I really dont know what to do
now I'm setting my pc on very very low powerplan
but this is honestly just unusable can anybody give me any advice on what to do
also if you wanna hear the sound I could send it on discord or something

Comment: Assuming it's cleaned out good, you could try some contact cleaner if you can get to the fan assembly itself and to the motor, but most likely the easiest thing to do is replace the fan as it is likely just worn out and no matter what you do this will keep recurring. It usually isn't too difficult and Google can get you a guide or a video... Can't say much more since you didn't tell us the make and model of your laptop.

Comment: I would replace the fan. The cost is minimal compared to what can happen with an overheated CPU.

Comment: @acejavelin i dont really know if my laptop is cleaned out good its a pain to open my laptop so i can acces the fan and i dont really think its worn out cause i have only owned this laptop for like 3/4 months and havent let it fall yet iirc

Comment: @CharlesKenyon my cpu isnt getting more heat but havent run cpu at full power yet(too scared to try my cpu at full power) so idk

Comment: If it is only 3 or 4 months old and you don't want to open it up to clean it out good or replace the fan, perhaps you should contact the manufacturer for a warranty repair. There isn't really a magic fix here, a rattle is a mechanical noise, it needs a mechanical fix.

Comment: seriously, a rattling fan is a bad sign. the bearings are not functioning properly, and it will get worse over time. eventually the fan will seize. if its a PWM fan, it will often report that it is down, and usually a motherboard will just shutdown if the bios/uefi detects that the CPU fan is non-functional. it may lead to a situation where the unit will not power on and boot. at that point its also rather hard to diagnose.

Comment: About 10 years ago, I had the fan go out without any noise. The CPU overheated when writing to the boot sector. Total failure of the hard drive. On a new computer you should be running your CPU at full power. You should not be afraid of this.

Comment: @keltari Yes that sound from the other question sound a lot like this sound